# Texture Annotation using OVRInput Touch Controller Raycast in Unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, raycasting, oculus

**EDIT2:**

Thanks to Draco in the comments referring me to the `LineRenderer` class.

Here is a link to a script that helped me draw ray lines in the game world space: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1142318/making-raycast-line-visibld.html

**EDIT:**

I changed the unit length from 1 to 100,000 and from black color to blue in the Debug.DrawRay method, and now I am able to see the rays drawn in the scene view only.

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.blue, 100000);
```

Also, I am now able to track the touch controller's ray by applying the below script to the game object `LocalAvatar` > `controller_right`.

**ORIGINAL POST**:

I am attempting to do something seemingly simple using the Oculus VR packages `OVRAvatar`, `OVRCameraRig`, and `OVRInput` in Unity 5.6.1 and Visual Studio C#.

Goal: **I want to get the raycast from my Oculus touch controller's pointer finger, and intercept a plane to apply pixels to the plane's texture.**

I was able to get the camera's raycast to intercept the plane using `OVRCameraRig` like so:

```
void Update() {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 fwd = ovrCamera.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ovrCamera.transform.position, fwd, out hit, 10000))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Plane"))
        {
            print("Hit the plane!");
            // apply some pixels to plane texture
            // setPixels(plane.texture)
        }
    }

 // EDIT: I changed the unit length from 1 to 100,000 and now I am able to see the rays drawn in the scene view only.
 // NOTE: this line below does not work in Unity's scene view or game view
 Debug.DrawRay(ovrCamera.transform.position, ovrCamera.transform.forward, Color.black, 1);
}
```

Aside from the `Debug.DrawRay` function not working, the code which checks for the OVRcamera's raycast hitting the plane does in fact work.

However, now that I am trying to test the raycast hit from `OVRInput.Controller.RTouch`, I am unable to see the drawn ray and the hit collider check is not triggered.

I have added this script below as a component to `OVRCameraRig's RightHandAnchor`:

```
void Update() {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, 10000))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Plane")
        {
            print("Hit plane with touch controller's raycast!");
        }
    }
  // EDIT: I changed the unit length from 1 to 100,000 and now I am able to see the rays drawn in the scene view only.
  // NOTE: this line below does not work in Unity's scene view or game view
 Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.black, 1);
}
```

Needless to say, the `Debug.DrawRay` function does not work here as well. I can't tell if the raycast from the touch controllers are actually being tracked.

Any help or insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The rays drawn by `Debug.DrawRay` are only visible in a scene view, not the game view. Might that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not seeing the rays in the Scene view either.  Maybe I am missing a project setting to allow the rays to be drawn?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Although without a final `true` parameter, the debug rays won't draw in front of other objects and because the ray is specified as origin and direction, they will only be 1 unit long (you may want `Debug.DrawLine` instead). But no, there's no settings that should need to be configured.

Comment: Got it. I made the unit length = 100k, and now I am able to see the rays. Thanks, Draco.  Now, I just need to be able to draw these same rays in the actual game view.

Comment: You can't get Debug rays to draw in the game view. Sorry! You'll need a Line Renderer or another solution.

Comment: Roger that.  Thank you for your help @Draco18s

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Draco in the comments referring me to the LineRenderer class.

Here is a link to a script that helped me draw ray lines in the game world space: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1142318/making-raycast-line-visibld.html

I changed the unit length from 1 to 100,000 and from black color to blue in the Debug.DrawRay method, and now I am able to see the rays drawn in the scene view only.

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.blue, 100000);
```

Also, I am now able to track the touch controller's ray by applying the below script to the game object LocalAvatar > controller_right.